# Why isn't there an "answered"-check icon on questions that have an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, accepted-answer

Could one tell from the top of a posted question whether it has already been "answered" or not? I could see a use of that to avoid having to scroll down when assessing whether a post is relevant or not.

Comment: If the post has answers, the checked answer only indicates that OP thinks that one helped him best. It doesn't mean anything about the relevance or the quality of the other answers.

Comment: Do we have any other qualities at this point? Isn't that quite an interesting quality of the "answer" then? :)

Comment: We have a post's score, but that does not necessarily indicate its quality.

Comment: Often, it is useful just to read someone else's description of the problem, even if there is no answer.

Answer (score 9):

Most places where you find links to questions already show this information *before* you navigate to the question. E.g. the main page, the search results, and the list with related questions.

That, combined with the fact that it doesn't convey much information at all (the checkmark says one person found the answer useful; a score of 20 says 20 people found the answer useful), is enough reason for me not to show it near the question on the question detail page.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel. I totally accept that this makes sense to you. Still to *me* the answer accepted by the orig poster carries a very important value, the fact that his/her particular problem was actually resolved by that suggestion. Another reason would probably be just for consistency' sake to have the green icon the header. Still this is all just from my side of things. I would even go as far as saying it would make sense for Google to have it the search results. Thanks anyway everyone for commenting on this.